# C# how to give reportviewer datasource from datagridview?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, report, reportviewer

I want my `ReportViewer` to print out my `DataGridView` values which are from my database.

My DataGridView is in `Form1` and ReportViewer in `Form2` and My rdlc file's DataSet is DataSet1.

I tried this method but only my rdlc design shows and not the data in tables:

```
{
    this.DBTableAdapter.Fill(this.DBDataSet1.Orders);
    BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
    ReportDataSource Rds = new ReportDataSource("DataSet1", bs);
    reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(Rds);
    this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
}
```

Comment: ReportViewer doesn't have anything to do with DataGridView.  Based on the context that you have shared, it's not clear what the problem is. You need to share more details.

Comment: I have a form with datagridview and a textbox and a button. i use the textbox and button to filter out datas in my gridview. after the button is clicked my reportviewer opens and the filtered data from datagridview shows in my reportviewer. basically i want my reportviewer to get the data from my gridview @RezaAghaei

Comment: ReportViewer doesn't get data from DataGridView, but it can use the dame data source as the DataGridView.

Comment: yes I have tried the code I mentioned in my question but it didn't work so I'm confused. pretty sure I should delete the "BindingSource" part and replace it with "Form1.datagridview1.datasource" but since my gridview is in another form this is not the way to call it. if you can help me with a better way to call gridview's datasource in another form it'll be a big help thank you @RezaAghaei